# (sml)Can anyone help me interpret the problem since I lack interpretation skills?

Tags: sml

- For your information, these problems are just solving what's circulating on some website.

I don't know exactly what the problem is even if I use the translator.

Does the defined `datatype 'a tree` and `val ex` mean to do in-order or prefix through lisp notation?

Or should I implement it in ML like listening?

I haven't solved a lot of questions, so I don't know exactly what I'm asking for, but I don't know the source of this problem, so there's no place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `val ex = ...` is just an example tree.

It seems like the question is asking you to do two things:

1. Implement `prettyprint`, a function which takes a `string tree` as input, traverses the tree in-order, and converts it to the Lisp notation. The output should be a `string`.
2. Implement `deepreverse`, a function which takes *any* tree as input and produces a new tree. The in-order traversal of the output tree should be reversed.

Comment: (defun f (x) 
  (let ((y 3))
   ;; At this point, x and y are lexical variables
  )
 )

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When I was solving the ML problem, I was surprised that the lisp language suddenly came out. Is the lisp language the same as this language?

Comment: SML and Lisp are quite different actually! But since both could be called "functional" languages, there is some overlap. In this problem, there's not actually any Lisp happening---it's just a string inspired by Lisp syntax.

Comment: Oh, it's a language inspired by lisp.
I thought the lisp language was emerging.
Thank you for your answer!